# Angular animate from controller

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Hi I am trying to animate my object from my controller. Basically, the html contains a image and when I change that from the controller I want to be able to animate it off the screen to the left or to the right. I have some basic things down but they don't seem to work.

CSS

```
.img-slide {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 350px;
}
.img-slide.ng-enter,
.img-slide.ng-leave {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
.img-slide.ng-enter {
    left: 100%;
}
.img-slide.ng-enter-active {
    left: 0;
}
.img-slide.ng-leave {
    left: 0;
}
.img-slide.ng-leave-active {
    left: -100%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class='row images'>
     <div class='col img-slide'>
         <img src="{{imgSlide}}"/>
     </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$scope.changeImg = function () {
    //This is where the scope var is update
    $scope.imgSlide = newImgSlide;

    //Code to add my animation here
};
```

Comment: I didn't want to include the whole project because it is much bigger than the snippets I included

Comment: You don't need the whole project, just make a fiddle with a quick angular boostrap and controller and drop your code in. Hard to tell how to help you without one.

Comment: It is super important to not focus on the ng-click that I added. This action has to be called from a function in the controller. https://jsfiddle.net/midevilworm/pk47k8Lb

Answer (score 0):

Midevilworm,
I made some adjustments to your code. There were a couple of problems (one was that your second image path couldn't be found.)

First, I added a new scope variable currentImage. Then, I put the images in an array. Next, I updated your imgSlide variable to be an object, like this:

```
$scope.imgSlide = {
    image: $scope.imagesArray[$scope.currentImage].img
}
```

Then, I edited your HTML to use ng-model, like this:

```
<div class='col img-slide' ng-model="imgSlide" >
    <img ng-src="{{imgSlide.image}}"/>
</div>
```

Finally, I edited your changeImg function so that it updates the value of $scope.currentImage and replaces the img property of the imgSlide object with the  item in the array at the index of $scope.currentImage.

Hope this helps.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bjDesign/ntdt8jsa/11/